# mysql one to one messaging optimized table query

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, database-schema

I got this schema to work with:

```
-- store messages between users
CREATE TABLE chat_messages (
    id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    sender_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    recipient_id BIGINT UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
    message_body TEXT,
    read_at DATETIME DEFAULT NULL,
    created_at DATETIME NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY(id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_messages_1 FOREIGN KEY (sender_id) REFERENCES profiles (id),
    CONSTRAINT FK_messages_2 FOREIGN KEY (recipient_id) REFERENCES profiles (id)
) ENGINE = INNODB;
```

I need to run a query against it to get a list of unique active chats for a user, I have this query:

```
SELECT * FROM chat_messages WHERE recipient_id = :user_id GROUP BY recipient_id ORDER BY created_at DESC
```

Which returns grouped rows, however:

1. The returned row includes message_body but it is not the latest message (thinking along the lines of a need to GROUP it BY the previously ordered data set)
2. Also, if the user sent messages to another user and did not receive a reply yet, it does not include it in the list (in that case the sender_id should be taken into consideration as well)

Any suggestions to have a performance focused query to achieve all that? Thanks :)

Comment: Actually, you may get the latest message_body as well, randomly. Or any message_body in between. This is an unfortunate consequence of [how GROUP BY works under MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-extensions.html) (quote: _"The server is free to choose any value from each group, so unless they are the same, the values chosen are indeterminate."_). Other DBMSes do the right thing and forbid columns in SELECT list that are neither aggregated nor mentioned in GROUP BY.

Answer (score 1):

You can do what you want with a `not exists` query:

```
SELECT cm.*
FROM chat_messages cm
WHERE recipient_id = :user_id AND
      NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1
                  FROM chat_messages cm2
                  WHERE cm2.recipient_id = cm.recipient_id AND
                        cm2.created_at > cm.created_at
                 )
ORDER BY created_at DESC;
```

For performance, you should have an index on `chat_messages(recipient_id, created_at)`.

Comment: Gordon, thank you for answering - much appreciated - it works for point 1. (it gets the last message), any potential extensions to do point 2. as part of this query? Or would it be better off to introduce a "chat_thread" table and reference as FK in chat_messages?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a query, which should fulfill your needs:

```
SELECT a.sender_id, a.recipient_id, a.message_body
FROM chat_messages a
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT IF(recipient_id=1, sender_id, recipient_id) user_id,
    MAX(created_at) created_at
  FROM chat_messages
  WHERE 1 IN (recipient_id, sender_id)
  GROUP BY IF(recipient_id=1, sender_id, recipient_id)
) recent
ON 
  (
    (a.sender_id = recent.user_id AND a.recipient_id = 1)
  OR
    (a.recipient_id = recent.user_id AND a.sender_id = 1)
  )
  AND a.created_at = recent.created_at
```

The inner join computes the dialog partner user ids and the date of the most recent message. This is joined with the whole table, to search the corresponding message and retrieve its content.

If you create an index on `(sender_id, recipient_id, created_at)` it can be used to support the execution. Nevertheless this query is not that light.

I have prepared a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/a4302/1) too.